# How to dynamically display data from a database in a vertical format in a table?

Tags: html, database, model-view-controller, html-table

This is the code that displays row data from the database in a horizontal format. I would like to be able to display the row data in a vertical manner.

```
    <table> 
       @foreach (var item in Model)
    {


        <tr>
            @foreach (var items in item.Numbers)
            {
                <td>@items.Number</td>
            }
        </tr>

    }

</table>
```

It is currently displaying this :

1 2 3 4 5 6 
 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
 
1 2 3 4 5 6

But I need to to display

1 1 1 1 1 1
 
2 2 2 2 2 2 
 
3 3 3 3 3 3
 
4 4 4 4 4 4
 
5 5 5 5 5 5 
 
6 6 6 6 6 6

Answer (score 0):

I would make the lists with

```
 <ul>@foreach (var items in item.Numbers){
    <li>@items.Number</li>
    }
 </ul>
```

Then adjusting it with CSS with margins and making it appear as if they are close. I'm not an expert but, that's how I would solve that.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to display it in a table.